# Replace line in aws cli output with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a script that I wrote that deletes AWS snapshots. I want to remove part of the output when a snapshot doesn't exist.

In this output:

```
Deleting unused snapshots in AWS Gov Non Prod
*****************************************************************
deleting snapshot: snap-0b571b64784bac904

An error occurred (InvalidSnapshot.NotFound) when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: The snapshot 'snap-0b571b64784bac904' does not exist.
*****************************************************************


*****************************************************************
Verify that snapshot: snap-0b571b64784bac904 is gone:

An error occurred (InvalidSnapshot.NotFound) when calling the DescribeSnapshots operation: The snapshot 'snap-0b571b64784bac904' does not exist.
*****************************************************************
```

I want to remove just the phrase: "An error occurred (InvalidSnapshot.NotFound) when calling the DescribeSnapshots operation:" and leave the phrase: The snapshot 'snap-0b571b64784bac904' does not exist.

In my script I tried adding sed to remove what I don't want:

```
aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id=$i --profile=govcloud-nonprod | sed -e 's/An error occurred (InvalidSnapshot.NotFound) when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: //g'
```

This is my script in its entirety:

```
    #!/bin/bash

echo "Deleting unattached volumes in AWS Lab"

for i in $(cat aws_lab_volumes.txt)
do
  echo "*****************************************************************"
  echo "deleting volume: $i"
  aws ec2 delete-volume --volume-id=$i --profile=lab | sed -e 's/An error occurred (InvalidVolume.NotFound) when calling the DeleteVolume operation: //g' 2>/dev/null
  echo "*****************************************************************"
  echo; echo; echo; echo; echo
  sleep 5
  echo "*****************************************************************"
  echo "Verify that volume: $i is gone:"
  aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids=$i --profile=lab | sed -e 's/An error occurred (InvalidVolume.NotFound) when calling the DescribeVolumes operation: //g' 2>/dev/null
  echo "*****************************************************************"
  echo; echo; echo; echo; echo
done
```

So basically the sed line is failing. How can I use sed to remove just the part I don't want?

Comment: works fine on your posted input fragment

Comment: weird! Works not at all for me the way I'd like it.

Comment: Try redirecting the aws output to a file and then run `file` on it:  `file awsOutput`.  If it doesn't say `awsOutput: ASCII text`, perhaps that's your issue.  I can't really see a lot else that could be going wrong here, unless you have sed aliased or a weird version of sed `alias sed` and `sed --version` to check that stuff.

Comment: OK thanks. I do get `awsOutput.txt: ASCII text` when I do a file on the output. I'm using sed 4.2.2 in Ubuntu 16.04. There is no alias for sed.

Comment: Hmm, you could try `sed -re 's/An error occurred \(InvalidSnapshot\.NotFound\) when calling the DescribeSnapshots operation:\s*?//g'` on the off-chance that last bit of whitespace is actually a tab.  Seems unlikely, though.

Comment: hey, thanks for the suggestion! I tried your exact line. Copied it into the script. No change! Still getting the unwanted output: `An error occurred (InvalidSnapshot.NotFound) when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: The snapshot 'snap-0306de74f59f83079' does not exist.`

Comment: @bluethundr - I got nothing.  Pretty sure the sed line is fine then.  Some bash script weirdness going on and the sed line is being malformed or not run is my guess.

Comment: Pipe the output to `sed '/DescribeSnapshots/s/^[^:]*:[ ]//'` (make sure your output is on `stdout` not `stderr`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: deleted first improvement, that has been used by OP.

This problem shouldn't be so difficult, but we have to try it in small steps.
You have followed my advice to add `2>/dev/null`, but wrote this on the wrong place:

```
aws ... --profile=lab | sed -e 's/...//g' 2>/dev/null
```

should be

```
aws ... --profile=lab 2>/dev/null | sed -e 's/...//g'
```

When this works you will be missing the whole line, so even better is

```
aws ... --profile=lab 2>&1 | sed -e 's/...//g'
```

When this doesn't help, try the next approaches:

**Review your code and what you have written in the code**
The example output shows `Deleting unused snapshots in AWS Gov Non Prod`, the code shows `echo "Deleting unattached volumes in AWS Lab"`.
*Are you testing the same file that you have been editing?*

**Make sure `#!/bin/bash` is on the first line without additional spaces**

**Debug with a temp file**
Redirect the aws output to a file and look at that file.

```
aws ... --profile=lab > /tmp/aws.out
vi /tmp/aws.out
```

(look voor special characters, TAB characters, ..)

Try simple commands with /tmp/aws.out

```
sed 's/An error/===/' /tmp/aws.out
sed 's/An error.*: /===/' /tmp/aws.out # something special in the part you try to match
sed 's/ /=/' /tmp/aws.out # Are all white spaces a space ?
sed 's/.*/===/' /tmp/aws.out # Can sed do anything at all or are you missing an EOL 
grep -v "An error" /tmp/aws.out # sed should be fine, but will this remove the complete line?
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the code per your observation. Still not getting the desired results with sed. Even when copying your suggested line verbatim. The code in the example is now as it is in the current form of the script. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Is a part written to stderr (what happens after adding `2>/dev/null`)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately writing to stderr did not do the trick. I've updated the code in the OP again to show the script as it is now.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the line: `aws ... --profile=lab 2>&1 | sed -e 's/...//g'` got it to do exactly what I needed it to do. Really appreciate your contribution!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have a  character that requires an escape, the dot "." and likely the parens "()" are going to need special attention in the sed search string, however; In this case there doesn't seem to be a need for large specific strings to search.  Try dumbing it down like so and increase string complexity from there.  This worked in my tests which I cat a file to stdout, however your command may send to stderr if so the second line should work for you.

```
aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id=$i --profile=govcloud-nonprod | sed 's/.*DescribeSnapshots.*: //'

aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id=$i --profile=govcloud-nonprod 2>&1 | sed 's/.*DescribeSnapshots.*: //'
```

Comment: I think it might be the 2nd case only of data output on stderr